# Visual Studio: cannot have multiple source files opened in different tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabs, visual-c++-2013

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2013/Visual C++ 2013, I cannot have multiple tabs showing multiple files. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
There is a tiny icon in the tab itself which needs to be clicked to keep it opened.